# php: extracting substring from a string

Tags: php

I have in my database record products and price on the same column. EG:

> product name 2- RM 120.00
>
> product name 6 - RM 10.00
>
> product name 77 - RM 1.00
>
> product name 3243 - RM 18.00

I am currently trying to separate the name & price into 2 columns, so the name column will only have 'product name' while price column only the price '120.00'

I tried using substr function but that would only work on the number number of characters behind. Is there anyway I can get all the numbers behind the '- RM' ?

Comment: You tried using substr - can you show us what you tried?

Comment: you can also use preg_match for your purpose, but frankly saying explode is a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = explode(" - RM ", $record); //your (string) database record in $record

echo $data[0]; //product name 2
echo $data[1]; //120.00

echo $data[2]; //product name 6
echo $data[3]; //10.00
```

Answer (score 0):

The explode function makes this pretty easy.

```
$values = explode(' - RM ', $field);
var_dump($values);
```